Can the addresses of two distinct variables of different types compare equal in C?
I'm having difficulties understanding an aspect of Strict Aliasing in C.
As far as I understand, pointers of incompatible types can't be converted between one another. But what about pointer comparisons between such different types, after casting them to void* or char*, or even to their numerical representation?
In C, (let's say C23) are the following asserts guaranteed?
int x = 1;
float y = 1.0f;

assert((void*)(&x) != (void*)(&y)); // always passes?
assert((char*)(&x) != (char*)(&y)); // always passes?

// something like a "reinterpret cast" to uint64_t
// or another type that is correct for some system
assert((uint64_t)(&x) != (uint64_t)(&y)); // always passes?


Why I'm asking: Is it allowed that the location of these two variables is numerically (or otherwise) equal; while for example a float might be stored in some kind of "float memory" and the int in some "int memory" that has the same address there, but the CPU looks in int memory or float memory depending on the type?
What I'm curious about is whether there could be two different stacks for example for different data types, (hypothetical example: store the floats on GPU memory and the ints in normal memory, or something like that, but the addresses compare equal across that hardware). Or is the compiler required to carry these differences back into the comparison operator?

What I found about this:

In 6.5.9 it says "If two pointers to object types both point to the same object, or both point
one past the last element of the same array object, they compare equal". I think it's not the same object, but I only see one direction if x then they compare, but not the inverse.
Not C but similarly, in C++ I read "Note that two pointers that represent the same address may nonetheless have different values." here. But I'm missing an example for my case.
an old newsgroup post

What I tried: I tried to make the asserts fail, but they worked everytime, but I was curious if they could fail theoretically if a Standard-compliant compiler did something special
Basically does the comparison make any sense across pointers of incompatible datatypes? If no, can it be "equal" despite different variables?

Clarification: I realize that compiling to assembler in a normal way might make these asserts always true, I'm curious though, if the C Standard guarantees that they are true (especially the first two, the last one is also interesting to me, but we can use another type, based on the target, intptr_t or any).

Re “pointers of incompatible types can't be converted between one another”: This is incorrect. A pointer to one object type may be converted to a pointer to another type, but the behavior is not defined if the alignment is not as required for the destination type. Strict aliasing is not involved unless the pointer is used to access an object in memory.

x and y declared as shown with automatic storage duration will be stored in distinct addresses so the pointers can never compare equal. The asserts will always pass. The compiler would be badly broken if you declare two separate variables that are used in your code (not subject to being optimized away) and the compiler attempted to store both values in a single memory address.

Use intptr_t instead of uint64_t to convert a pointer to integer.

@AdamSho,  assert((uint64_t)(&x) != (uint64_t)(&y)); could fail when addressing is wider than 64-bit as (uint64_t) truncates.  Not something expected though until the 2040s or later.

@AdamSho The first 2 asserts are certainly good, yet you are wading in deep spec waters.  You may want to allow a few days on this post.

@EricPostpischil n3220 draft page 87 (link is in question)

@chux i still don't understand though how the first two asserts are guaranteed by the standard

the uint64_t example is just an example for a specific target, probably the other two asserts are closer to my question, but i'm still curious about the numeric comparison (intptr_t fine too) as well

@EricPostpischil the quote is another sentence (the one at the bottom of the question). the top one is isn't a quote, its just my understanding. sorry, can't edit my previous comment

As far as standard C is concerned, it avoids the term addresses when it can, because the nature of addresses is implementation-defined. The C standard does assume that addresses are constant through the object's lifetime though (C17 6.2.4).
During optimization the compiler might make assumptions in cases where the variable definitions are visible to the translation unit and come up with conclusions like "well these two are not allocated on the same address". Not so much because the C standard says so, but because the given compiler port knows the addresses at compile-time.
The standard does guarantee a few things:

The part in C17 6.5.9 says that "Two pointers compare equal if and only if..." "...both are pointers to the same object". Which isn't the case in your example. void* is treated specially when present, also from 6.5.9:

If one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, the former is converted to the type of the latter.


The special case where two variables may share the same address, as far as the C standard is concerned, is union. Then the C standard (C17 6.5.8) guarantees equivalence: "All pointers to members of the same union object compare equal." These would have the same address but different values.
C++ is different from C here, why you shouldn't be reading C++ documentation. C supports type punning between union members by reinterpreting the memory as another type. C++ does not support it (so union is made good for nothing in that language).


Pedantically, the standard doesn't guarantee that pointers to incompatible types have the same address representation, only that if converting from one object pointer type to another and back, you will end up with a pointer comparing equal to what you had to begin with (C17 6.3.2.3 §7). So in theory there could be different pointer representations for different pointed-at types, but in that case the compiler would have to deal with the conversions between these different formats internally in some cumbersome manner, which is why you are unlikely to find any real-world implementation like that.
Real-world examples from semi-exotic microcontroller hardware gives plenty of cases where data could be stored in banks beyond the standard address range, which is then picked separately before accessing the data. That could cause optimized C code to break in regards of pointer comparisons, which is why pointers in code accessing memory like that is very likely declared volatile, and/or alternatively using non-standard extensions near/far.

Detail: "pointer comparing equal to what you had to begin" --> does not mean the same bit pattern, just that they are equivalent - point to the same location.  I do not mean to say you implied otherwise - just a detail.

Does pedentically mean that the asserts can fail? union is different, i agree. I just wonder if a compiler must guarantee that the asserts I asked about (especially the first two) must pass, according to the standard. (kind of unsure also about the distinct memory location aspect for different types, how that translates for pointer comparison). Or does void*/char* cast before the comparison signals to a compiler that the comparison must work? (Because I can't compile float* == int* for example)

your real-world semi-exotic example is interesting, do you know if that's C standard compliant?

@AdamSho There is nothing in the standard indicating that they can fail even though converted to void* - I think the key is that they point at different objects. Or otherwise the whole language will come crashing down. There's a constraint in the == operator saying that pointers must point at compatible types, why float* == int* won't work.

@AdamSho The microcontroller example is standard compliant as far as the hardware not guaranteeing that the value at a certain location is the same as the last time it was accessed, meaning it is up to the application programmer to use volatile. Or otherwise use non-standard extensions.

The Standard also expressly provides that a pointer which is "one past" the last element of an array will compare equal to a pointer to an object which immediately follows the array in storage, though both clang and gcc in practice sometimes treat such comparisons as an invitation to perform unsound inferences, which effectively lead to "anything can happen" UB.

It's practically impossible for an implementation to have "int memory" and "float memory" because any suitably aligned memory (such as that returned by malloc) can be used to hold either. In fact, the same memory can hold int and float values without an intervening realloc. Just overwriting the old values is sufficient. Hence, you can hold an int* and float* pointer to the same malloc'ed memory, and write values consecutively.
Because you can free either the int* or the float* they have to be equivalent (of course you can't free them both).
However, there is nothing in C that specifies that all bits of a pointer contribute to the value representation. An implementation can use a few non-value bits to encode sizeof(T), for instance. If you look at those non-value bits through an intptr_t your int* and float* could differ.

OP's has it more correct. "It's practically impossible for an implementation to have "int memory" and "float memory" negates OP's good understanding that an int * pointer and float * may have the same bit pattern.  Yet when converted to void *, the void * patterns differ and are not equivalent and so fail a compare.  OTOH, systems that employ different encoding/size for various object types are now rare and so make the issue rarely applicable.

@chux: I think you're overlooking something. Assume a physical system which does have a int memory and a float memory, such that 1 is a valid hardware pointer in both. That is to say, a hardware store of a float register to address 1 writes to float mem, but using the exact same bits when storing an int register writes to int mem. In such systems, you have an issue implementing malloc: it won't know how you're going to use the memory.  It can only work by returning an address that's free in both int mem and free in float mem. IOW, C would be a bad fit for this sort of CPU.

Disagree about bad fit.  malloc() returns void * and free() receives a void *.  Your example starts with int *, and float * yet is missing how void * converts to/from int */float * - it is not necessarily also a 1.  IAC, such exotics are quite uncommon these days.

@chux: The problem is that the described hardware physically doesn't have void* memory, but it does have int* memory and float* memory. C does support code memory and data memory. As a result, you can at the same time have both a void(*)(void) with value 1 and a void* with value 1.

malloc is an interesting case. Though my understanding, malloc/free might be implemented using another mechanism that doesn't relate to user-faced pointer comparison at all? But let's even say a compiler would guarantee the assert for heap memory, but not for stack memory, iiuc the question still holds. Basically if I use different memory hardware (or lets say, data structures) for different types, would I be allowed to fail the asserts but at the same time have a "fork" somewhere in my runtime (not user-faced, based on an internal representation) that finds the data? thats what I'm wondering.

In both clang and gcc, if a region of storage has ever held a T with a certain bit pattern, and is later reused as type U, attempting to write a U whose bit pattern matches the earlier T may cause the Effective Type of the storage to revert to T.

No cites provided, just a community wiki starting point.
IMO, a detailed answer involves quite a bit and better if OP narrowed the question.

Keep in mind that in C,  there are special issues concerning:
void*
object pointers (not character pointers)
object pointers (character pointers)
function pointers
null_ptr_t (C2X)


Can the addresses of two distinct variables of different types compare equal in C?

For object pointers: no, not when the 2 pointers are converted to void *.


As far as I understand, pointers of incompatible types can't be converted between one another. But what about pointer comparisons between such different types, after casting them to void* or char*, or even to their numerical representation?

Object pointers
Object pointers of one type can be converted to object pointers of another type with conditions.

It is representable in the target type?

Function pointers
Function pointers conversion to/from other function pointers is fine.  Otherwise limitations apply.


In C, (let's say C23) are the following asserts guaranteed?

Yes, when x, y are objects
assert((void*)(&x) != (void*)(&y)); // always passes?
assert((char*)(&x) != (char*)(&y)); // always passes?

Comparison via conversion to an integer has limitations:
assert((uint64_t)(&x) != (uint64_t)(&y));


Range, Is the integer type wide enough?  Note that a wide enough type is not required to exist, yet if it does, (u)intptr_t will do the job for object pointers.

Pointer compare is not the same as integer compare.  2 pointers may point to the same address yet not compare the same as integers.  2 pointers may point to the different addresses yet compare the same as integers when the integer type is not wide enough.




Is it allowed that the location of these two variables is numerically (or otherwise) equal; while for example a float might be stored in some kind of "float memory" and the int in some "int memory" that has the same address there, but the CPU looks in int memory or float memory depending on the type?

Yes, OP is correct, although that is rarely seen these days.


What I'm curious about is whether there could be two different stacks for example for different data types, (hypothetical example: store the floats on GPU memory and the ints in normal memory, or something like that, but the addresses compare equal across that hardware). Or is the compiler required to carry these differences back into the comparison operator?

It depends on how addresses compare.  Comparing 2 object pointers via void * conversion is well defined and the 2 pointers will differ.  Other cases risk issues.


... in C++ ...

Not addressing another language here.


Basically does the comparison make any sense across pointers of incompatible datatypes?

No, not in general.  void *, char *, nullptr_t have their speciall issues.
Best advice:

Handle object pointers and function pointers separately.

Convert object pointer to void * before attempting mix type compares.

Avoid casting a pointer to an integer type to do any math ops, compare, add, etc.




but we can use another type, based on the target, intptr_t or any.

Not for highly portable code.  C does not specify that an integer type exists that faithfully round-trips object_pointer --> void * --> integer --> void * --> (_object_pointer_type) equivalent_pointer.
Still the optional types (u)intptr_t do exist and do the job.  Recall that an equivalent_pointer bitpattern may differ from the original pointer yet still compare == as 1.

You are mistaken. There is no real distinction between object, function, and all other types of pointers you listed. There are just pointers.

@WhiteOwl  I suspect "no real difference" is not based on the C spec, less  than 15 years C experience and non-embedded C use.  Should you want to learn about those differences, consider posting a question as what are the differences of object, function, etc. pointers.

@WhiteOwl: there are machines where function pointers are distinctly different from object pointers. Once upon a long time ago (mid-80s), there were word-addressed machines where the char pointer value for a particular location was different from the 'anything bigger than char' pointer value for the same location. It was crucial to declare char *malloc() (because void * wasn't a type yet and <stdlib.h> wasn't a header yet) and to cast the result of malloc() to the correct type (because there wasn't—and still isn't—an automatic conversion from char * to any other pointer type).

@JonathanLeffler I never met such machines in real life. Even in the 80s, all computers of all types were having a single RAM . There were such thing as mixed memory models with long function pointers and near heap/data pointers (or vice versa). But they were still pointers. And yes, you could get a pointer to function and read it as a regular array. Still shooting yourself in a foot, but possible.

@WhiteOwl: I worked on a word-addressed machine (and learned C on it).  The machine was an ICL Perq (rebranded from Three Rivers).  The IBM AS/400 (iSeries?) has function pointers that are twice the size of data pointers, IIRC. Other mainframe systems had special handling for function pointers — ICL 1900 and 2900, for examaple.

"twice as long pointers" was not a unique thing. Look at memory models: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_models . But guess what - it was still the very same RAM and if you wanted, you could convert "far" pointer to a "near" one or back. Unless you have two different physical RAMs (one for data, one for code) - there would not be any real difference between variable and function pointers. And yes, I worked with such computers - but they were primitive enough to not be able to handle C, just not enough RAM.

@WhiteOwl: A "far" data pointer may only be converted to a "near" data pointer and back if the pointer identifies something in the primary data segment; a "far" code pointer may only be converted to a "near" code pointer and back if the pointer identifies something in the same code segment as the code converting it back.  Code and data pointers would only be interchangeable for such conversions when using the "tiny" memory model.

Once you went that far, it is highly advisable that you learn and have a real life practice with assembler. This would give you an understanding of what memory and pointers really are.
High level languages are trying to hide pointers since they can be confusing and dangerous if not used properly. In C, compiler gives you some warnings, in C++ there are much more warnings, in Asm - there is none.
But getting to your practical questions - yes you can store variables of different type in the same pointer, or more precisely to look at one variable is if it has a different type:
float f = 1234.56;
float *fp = &f;
void *vp = fp;
int *ip = vp;
int i = *ip;

In this example - all three pointers (fp, vp, ip) are pointing to the same physical place in memory. And both f and i are also coincide in the same memory. There is no real advantage for such conversion, but it can be done.
You will however have a real case of converting from any type to char* for debugging or audit purposes. For example, if you are doing some network messaging and want to see what is actually send/received:
struct message {
    float f;
    int i;
    char str[10];
} msg;

recieve(&msg, sizeof(msg));

for( int idx=0, char *c = &msg; idx < sizeof(msg); idx++, c++ )
    printf("%02X ", *c);

This will print you contents of the structure byte by byte, regardless of types used inside the structure.

int *ip = vp; has a problem when the alignment needs of an int exceed that of float.  That is not seen on any implementation in my experience, yet had the code sample swapped int/float, then it is reasonably possible a float alignment needs exceed int and code sample is `UB.

Alignment is a different wrinkle in that. It will affect performance (even if it is just milliseconds). And as I mentioned already - there is no much practical sense in such conversions, so it is left as undefined in text books and documentation. It is a sure way to shoot yourself in a foot, yes. But it is still possible to do.

Disagree with "but it is still possible to do".  "It will affect performance" or perhaps a bus fault, or any other UB.  "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Isn't such conversion problematic at some point for strict aliasing reasons, for int and float? when dereferencing, and if dereferencing should never point to the same loc if the types are incompatible in that way, wouldn't the "inverse" (comparing equal) be possible since the dereferencing isn't defined for that anyway? since conversion is allowed though, that means that the runtime would need to track the real data somewhere even across voids. It's not about assembler for me, but about other architectures where C can run. The standard doesn't forbid that afaik.

Also, a matching alignment requirement isn't a free ticket for strict aliasing circumvention, or is it?

@chux, Sorry, you are completely mistaken. Alignment has nothing to do with ability to assign an arbitrary type to a pointer. The example I shown - is an fragment from real life code. It is possible to do. It is pointless and wrong from logical point of view, but allowed from language point of view. It is compilable and executable. Pointless, but real.

@AdamSho, no there is no checking in real time for what was the original data type. Yes, it can lead to a lot of errors. Yes, you need to remember yourself what is that pointer actually points to... That is why people do not like pointers and invent languages without them. You must learn assembler, regardless of architecture or CPU. Any flavor of asm will do - it is the best way to understand how memory and computer in general actually works.

@WhiteOwl Having an example is good yet insufficient to show it is always good per the C spec.  A common alignment issue occurs when a pointer, say int16_t *, must point to a even address.  On some systems, its OK to assign an odd (access with odd pointer is slow), others, OK to assign an odd (and a bus fault when used), others simply UB to attempt the odd assignment.

int16_t is an absolute equivalent to signed short int it has nothing to do with any addresses. Modern compilers and linkers do try to do alignment automatically - yes. There are a special keywords in compilers to control alignment - yes. Does it affect conversion of float* into int* - absolutely no.
